# When is a paper said to be refereed?

Tags: journals, peer-review, conference

I have a conference paper that will be published in Lecture Notes in Computer Science, by Springer. [This question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/56397/is-lecture-notes-by-springer-a-journal) asked if Lecture Notes is a journal, and the general consensus was that it is not.

I received reviews on the paper, does that make it refereed? Or is a paper only said to be refereed if it is published in a journal?

Comment: My understanding is that it is a refereed conference.

Comment: Unfortunately being refereed is not a binary thing. Conferences vary greatly in the level of rigor of their review procedures, and disciplines vary greatly in the extent to which they consider conference proceedings publications to be peer-reviewed. It also depends on the context of the question: the standards applied in the context of a tenure promotion in certain university departments would depend on university policies and may differ than the standards of the field the tenure candidate is publishing in, etc.... So the answer, as in much else in life, is It Depends.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, note that there is a difference between refereed in a peer-review journal and refereed in a conference proceedings. It sounds like your case is the latter.

In both cases you are correct in saying it received peer review (if it did), but the moniker of 'refereed', in my mind, suggests the work could be rejected.

You note that you received 'reviews' but it isn't clear whether these are non-binding 'comments' or part of a dialog ending with accept/reject. If they were indeed just comments, and there was no possibility for rejection, I would not say it was 'refereed'.  Like in sports, referees make calls, not suggestions.

Comment: I agree that this was conference proceedings. There were four reviewers who provided us with comments, and the message began with saying that the paper was indeed accepted.

Comment: The conferences I know that publish their proceedings in LNCS are all refereed -- as in your paper can indeed be rejected for inclusion in the conference (and therefore the proceedings). I cannot be sure this is the case for the OP though.