# Where does one add a Springer LNCS publication in their CV?

Tags: publications, journals, conference, cv

I was wondering where people add Springer LNCS or LNAI publications in their CV or list of publications, if they were to specify conference, journal or monograph separately.

Whereas Springer itself says it is not a journal, the wiki page says it is a collection of books whereas Scimago Journal and country rank treats it as a journal. I was always of the opinion earlier that it is kind of similar to a conference proceedings and could be listed under such if one were to categorize. Now I am not too certain.

Can someone clarify?

Comment: Could you specify to which **wiki** you are refering? Is there a Springer Wiki listing all of their journals and collections?

Comment: Related: [Is Lecture Notes by Springer a journal?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/56397/is-lecture-notes-by-springer-a-journal)

Comment: Here's the wiki I meant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lecture_Notes_in_Computer_Science.

As to your other question about all their journals, I am sorry but I don't know the answer to that.

Comment: @ff524 Yes I noticed that one. I was more concerned with how you list it in a CV. I already got the idea that it is least likely to be considered as a journal.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since a LNCS publication can either be a monography or conference proceedings volume, the natural solution is to **ignore** the fact that it's a LNCS publication and just list it corresponding to its actual type, that is, proceedings volume (or entry therein), or monography.

Comment: I guess you're right. I only saw it as a proceedings volume. Didn't know it could be a monography.